# Selenium WebDriver: Mouse pointer interrupting the execution on Internet Explorer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have come across a weird situation with IE browser, where webdriver doesn't clicks on a submit button if my mouse pointer is in browser area.
But if I move the pointer to the corner (out of browser), then it clicks on the button.
Please help if anyone else has faced this kind of situation and what could be the possible solution. I had thought of moving the mouse out of browser area, to make it work, but not really sure how to move the mouse pointer in the corner.

Comment: Other browsers are ok like chrome/ firefox?

Comment: Yes.. its fine with other browsers.